# UnauthorizedAccessException using Copy-Item on remote fileserver

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to copy about 10 folders each containing a ~3KB .txt file onto a remote fileshare with some seconds latency. I'm using Powershells `Copy-Item` like this:

```
try
{
    Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    Write-Error $_.Exception.ToString()
}
```

The user running the script has read, write and execute permissions on the fileserver share and on the local source.

On first run, the destination folder is empty. Everything works fine. 
On second run, the files and folders already exist. So before running the code above I first run a check using `Test-Path` and in case the folder exists a delete using `Remove-Item` like this:

```
try
{
    if(Test-Path -Path $path -ErrorAction Stop)
    {
         Remove-Item -Recurse -Path $path -ErrorAction Stop
    }
}
catch
{
    Write-Error $_.Exception.ToString()
}
```

Nobody else edits those files. However, when running the script a dozent times, once in a while, for a reason I don't understand, i'm suddenly getting **UnauthorizedAccessException** errors for some of the folders while copying. The exact error is:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: access denied
>   ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: access denied
>   in Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.NativeDirectoryExists(String
>   path) in
>   System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.IsItemContainer(CmdletProvider
>   providerInstance, String path, CmdletProviderContext context

**please note: I'm getting those errors AFTER the deletion of the old files on the remote fileserver has compleated successfully.**

Answer (score 1):

This is a years old post but maybe one can benefit from that. You don't have to remove beforehand. You can just use `-Force` to override existing files.

```
try
{
    Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop -Force
}
catch
{
    Write-Error $_.Exception.ToString()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may need try to run the command line as Administrator.

Answer (score -3):

Masi, Powershell copy-item function is not really that great IMO. Why not use robocopy/Powershell hybrid here?

Example:

```
$source = "C:\temp"

$destination ="\\\RemoteServer\Temp"

robocopy $source $destination /s /mt:8
```

Comment: well, simply because it's not a good design. you're mixing non object oriented code with simple text producing commands. There are many disadvantages in this like error handling. using cmdlets will return objects which I then can use later on. It's like using *ping* when you got *test-connection*.